# ERROR: syntax error at or near "insert"

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estoy haciendo un disparador en sql (postgres). tengo el siguiente problema:

```
ALTER TABLE table_libros ALTER COLUMN update_m SET NOT NULL

CREATE TABLE items   (
    id                  INT NOT NULL,
    update_m            timestamp
 );


CREATE TRIGGER insert_date AFTER INSERT ON table_libros FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO table_flotante(id, update_m) VALUES(NEW.id, NOW())
```

> syntax error at or near "insert"
> SQL state: 42601

Estoy tratando de hacer un disparador cuando se inserte una nueva fila en la tabla libros, y que se guarde en otra tabla, la información de la actualización y fecha.

El problema está en insert. Gracias por sus aportes

Comment: pusiste como nombre de un campo la palabra reservada update?

Comment: Si, es un nombre pero ya modifico para que no se entienda mal

Comment: ¿Podrías por favor especificar el dialecto de SQL que estás usando? ¿Es MySQL? ¿Es SQLServer? ¿Es Oracle? ¿Es Postgresql? Esa información es fundamental para responder tu pregunta. Los errores de sintaxis dependen del dialecto que estés usando.

Comment: @JaimeMenendez Después de google "sql 42601", es probable que el dialecto sea Postgres.

Comment: @JaimeMenendez es postgres

Comment: Prueba con [algo como esto](https://pastebin.com/JmdJ6YSZ). Cuando creas un trigger se espera un procedimiento o una función a ser ejecutada, no un insert.

Answer (score 3):

En `postgresql` a diferencia de otros motores, es necesario crear en primer lugar una función que retorne un trigger:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_insert_date() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN

   INSERT INTO table_flotante(id, update_m) 
         VALUES(NEW.id, NOW());

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Y luego sí, podremos asociar la función al trigger en particular:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_date
    AFTER INSERT ON table_libros
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION fn_insert_date();
```

Te sugiero continuar leyendo la [documentación oficial](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/plpgsql-trigger.html).

Comment: Hola gracias, y por ejemplo si quiero que la fecha del sistema me salga en un formato de YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM. Esto lo pondría dentro de la función? puedes ayudarme con alguna guía? yo pensaba poner dentro   de la función            SELECT CONVERT(updated_m, GETDATE(), 120) AS [YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM];  pero no me agarra

Comment: Una columna fecha no tiene formato, es un objeto normalmente un número. Cuando se muestra por pantalla se representa con algún formato. Lo que quieres hacer no tiene sentido si la columna es un timestamp, ahora si quieres guardarlo como cadena (cosa que no te recomiendo) entonces si tendría sentido lo que quieres hacer

Comment: Gracias por el consejo!